ASP .NET MVC - Throwing an exception when attempting to modify a read-only session
Say you managed to make the session read-only by applying
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]

on a controller.
When modifying the session within that controller, it seems like changes will only last for the duration of the current request and will be silently discarded by the beginning of the next request.
I tried to search for a way to throw an exception when attempting to modify the session within that controller, rather than silently ignoring the changes, but failed to find one. It seems like there might be something to do with HttpSessionStateWrapper and IHttpModule, but I can't get this to work.
Is there any way to achieve this?

SessionState, I believe is set at Controller level(not Action level); Maybe you can set it at Action level to whatever you want by overriding the controller's session state level. See this link for help: https://techatfingers.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/session-state-on-action/

@SoftwareDveloper Thank you, I already implemented what this article suggests. My Issue comes afterwards. Once the session is indeed in a readonly state, I just want attempts to modify it to throw an exception instead of being silently discarded at the end of the request, that was the point of my question.
